# SQL Storing bit that is 7 digits long

Tags: mariadb

I'm using MariaDB on my computer. I'm a student so I'm not 100% familiar with the terms, but I've been told we are using SQL Server I believe. I'm using MariaDB 10.10 which I've installed on my laptop.

My objective was to create a table for airline flights that shows what days the flights operate on. I have been instructed to use the BIT(7) type and store zeros and ones to represent the days of the week the flight will operate on. Example given was “1010111”. This would mean the flight operates on Monday, Wednesday, Friday, Saturday, and Sunday. However, I do not have to convert the zeros or ones to say the day of the week. It can simply show as 1010111.

I can't get my field to show 7 bits. Here is what I have:

```
create table FlightConcession (
    FlightNo VARCHAR(7) not null primary key unique, 
    Origin TEXT not null, 
    Destination TEXT not null, 
    DayOfTheWeek BIT(7) not null, 
    TimeOfDay TIME not null
);

INSERT INTO FlightConcession VALUES('AA3254', 'Abilene', 'Dallas', B'1010111', '060000');
```

The output I get from this is:

| FlightNo | Origin | Destination | DayOfTheWeek | TimeOfDay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA3254 | Abilene | Dallas | W | 06:00:00 |

I don't know why it is outputting "W" instead of "1111100". The instructions we have received in class was minimal and I'm not making any traction from classmates or instructor assist. Can anyone please explain how I can get the display out for DayOfTheWeek to show "1111100" instead of a single character using the BIT(7) type? Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Understood. Thank you for posting this information. I have modified my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with data which you have inserted and the result.

If output is `W`, then the binary presentation should be `1010111`, but not `1111100`. The latter one has the value 124 and should be displayed as a vertical bar `|`.

To get the string representation of a bit field, use the BIN function:

```
SELECT  FlightNo, Origin, Destination, bin(DayOfTheWeek) as DayOfTheWeek, TimeOfDay from FlightConcession
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I apologize. I changed the input data as I was afraid no one would understand what the vertical line would be. I have updated the above code to be correct.

Comment: Am I wrong in understanding that this is actually something we do when we are searching through the data of the table rather than ensuring the data is displayed as ones and zeroes when someone using SELECT to search through the data? I was thinking that I built the table incorrectly.

Comment: BIT columns in result sets are binary data and have to be converted to the desired format. If they would be strings  it wouldn't be possible to perform bit operations.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and feedback. This did help to solve my problem. I was unaware that BIT could not display as a STRING of zeroes and ones and my instructor never alluded to this in her discussion notes. Thank you for the help in using the SELECT bin() as this worked for me.